# Accessing a JSON file in tomcat war and reading it

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to read a json file placed in `resources/data/info.json` in my webapp. Got to know that need to use `Convertor.class.getResourceAsStream("\\WEB-INF\\classes\\data\\Address.json");` where Convertor is my util class for some reason am unable to read the file and i see the `InputStream` returning null and i see the below exception :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 1, column: 0]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4133)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3988)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3058)
        at com.wf.hrca.util.Convertor.unMarshal(Convertor.java:84)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resources` is a folder of your source project on your development machine. Tomcat doesn't care about how your source project looks like. And by the way, when you'll deploy the application in production, there won't be any source project on the machine.

All Tomcat cares about is the war file you deploy. Inside this war file, the WEB-INF/classes directory, along with all the jar files under WEB-INF/lib, constitute the classpath of the application.

`Convertor.class.getResourceAsStream()`, as the javadoc explains (but you really need to read it to know) expects a `/`-separated path. If the path starts with a `/`, then the path starts at one of the roots of the classpath (i.e. `/` refers to WEB-INF/classes, and to the root of each jar file of WEB-INF/lib).

So, find where the json file is located inside the war file. If it's under `/WEB-INF/classes/data/info.json`, then you should use

```
Convertor.class.getResourceAsStream("/data/info.json");
```

Comment: i already tried it and see null in the `InputStream` that is returned when i do SOP. Also tried full path but the exception updated does not change.

Comment: So, where is the file located inside the war file? Post the output of `jar tvf yourwarfile.war`. Don't try random things. If the documentation says the path is `/`-separated, why do you think using backslashes is a good idea?

Comment: you know what am using windows 10 and was using \\ and was not working when i used `/` it just worked why so ...!!!

Comment: Because, as I already told you several times, getResourceAsStream doesn't expect the path of a file on the file system. It expects **a `/`-separated path** starting at the root of the classpath. Again, read the javadoc. Don't make wild guesses. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-